# PHP: mysqli fetch_all "crashes" on execution

Tags: php, linux, mysqli

I want to get all the rows from a table and store them in an array. Whenever fetch_all is used, the page crashes without any error messages. All other fetch options (fetch_assoc, fetch_array, etc..) work.

Code snippet that calls getcourses.php:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'getcourses.php',
      success: function(data){
           //do stuff
      }
 });
```

getcourses.php:

```
<?php
  require('includes/db.php');

  $query = "SELECT * FROM course";

  if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    $result->close();
  }
  $mysqli->close();
?>
```

db.php:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$db = 'db'; 
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
```

PHP version is 5.4.16 (CLI). The operating system is GNU. mysqlnd **is** installed.

This exact code **does** work on my ubuntu server with PHP version 7.2.24.

I am aware I can make a loop and use $result->fetch_assoc. However, getting this to work would be much better.

Comment: How many rows are you trying to fetch from the DB at once here?

Comment: You must get the error message first, then act.

Comment: By the way,  5.4.16 is **unacceptably** old.

Comment: I'm aware 5.4.16 is incredibly old, I'm not the one in control of the server. $mysql->error doesn't contain anything because the query isn't failing, just fetch_all.

Comment: $mysql->error is not the only source of error messages. you must check web-server logs, configure PHP to log errors, do anything to get the error message, not just telling everyone $mysql->error is empty. Getting the error message is **the only** way to deal with your issue and no stranger can tell you it. Only your system can